# Turbolinks friendly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, url, turbolinks

165 / 5000
Resultados de traducción
my problem is that when I try to enter a link with a friendly url turbolinks it gives me an error saying "Not acceptable" and asking me to complete it, for example.

```
    <a href="home?lang=es">home</a>
```

when I enter the turbolinks link it sends me the error 406 Not acceptable.

available variants "home.html"

I tried to solve in the .htaccess but every time I had to correct more errors and if I wanted to add another GET variable I had to create another friendly URL

```
    <a href="home?lang=es&id=1">home</a>
```

for it to work I had to add it like this

```
    <a href="home.html?lang=es&id=1">home</a>
```

for it
i guess its because turbolinks looks for it without adding the html, but is there any way to make it add it or fix this error?

**PD:** I use turbolinks cdn, I don't use rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some time searching in forums I found an answer in which I proposed to remove `this.xhr.setRequestHeader ("Accept", "text / html, application / xhtml + xml")` from turbolinks.js which worked perfect!

[original answer](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/308)

Comment: `"text / html, application / xhtml + xml"` - that looks wrong to begin with and would indeed fail if that was the way it was written. It should not have all those spaces... it should be `"text/html, application/xhtml+xml"`.